# If $\cos(a+b)\sin(c+d)=\cos(a-b)\sin(c-d)$, then $\cot(a)\cot(b)\cot(c)$ is

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos(a+b)\sin(c+d)=\cos(a-b)\sin(c-d)$, then what is $\cot(a)\cot(b)\cot(c)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing both sides by $\cos(a-b)\sin(c+d)$, we get,
$$\frac{\cos(a+b)}{\cos(a-b)} = \frac{\sin(c-d)}{\sin(c+d)}$$
Using componendo and dividendo,
$$\frac{\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)}{\cos(a+b)-\cos(a-b)}=\frac{\sin(c-d)+\sin(c+d)}{\sin(c-d) - \sin(c+d)}$$
$$\frac{2\cos(a)\cos(b)}{-2\sin(a)\sin(b)}=\frac{2\sin(c)\cos(d)}{-2\cos(c)\sin(d)}$$
$$2\cot(a)\cot(b)=2\tan(c)\cot(d)$$
Therefore,
$$\cot(a)\cot(b)\cot(c)=\cot(d)$$

Answer (score 0):

There's a minus sign missing on the RHS in your solution. By angle addition formulas and [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) we have by dividing both sides by $\cos(a+b)\sin(c-d)$ $$\frac{\cos(a-b)}{\cos(a+b)}=\frac{\sin(c+d)}{\sin(c-d)}$$
$$\frac{\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)}=\frac{\sin(c)\cos(d)+\cos(c)\sin(d)}{\sin(c)\cos(d)-\cos(c)\sin(d)}$$
$$\frac{\cos(a)\cos(b)}{\sin(a)\sin(b)}=\frac{\sin(c)\cos(d)}{\cos(c)\sin(d)}$$
$$\cot(a)\cot(b)=\tan(c)\cot(d)$$

Thus
$$\cot(a)\cot(b)\cot(c)=\cot(d).$$

Comment: You are right. I have corrected my answer.